# std::vector saving only last one element pushed

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have created 2 classes, `algorithm` and `peopleEncoding`:

- `peopleEncoding` has a private attribute `_solution` which is a `std::vector` containing integers.
- `algorithm` has a private attribute `_population` which is a `std::vector` containing pointers to `solutionEncoding` instances.

The `algorithm` class also has a method called `initPopulation` which fills `_population` like this:

```
void initPopulation (unsigned peopleQuantity){
    solutionEncoding * newOne = new solutionEncoding();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < peopleQuantity; i++ ){
        newOne->generateRandom();
        this->_population.push_back(newOne);
    }
}
```

If I print `_solution` attribute from `peopleEncoding` instances stored at `_population` (just after the `push_back` line) I get the expected results but if I do it after the loop encloser bracket the vector changes (they all are the same, equal to the last one pushed).

I´m not sure about the correct use of `new`.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. `peopleEncoding has a private attribute` Instead of writing your interpretation or description, please just post the code. Code speaks 1000 words. Really writing `struct solutionEncoding { std::vector<int> _solution; };` is _very_ clear what is what. `not sure about the correct use of "new"` Your code push_back the same pointer over and over again - it's the same pointer, same data, all _point_ to the same location.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem

This line:

```
this->_population.push_back(newOne);
```

pushes back at the end of the `_population` vector a pointer `newOne` that points to a `solutionEnconding`.  Since you initialize this pointer only one,  it's the same pointer to the same object that is used in all the items of the `_population` vector.

### The expectations

When you call this member function:

```
   newOne->generateRandom();
```

you probably change some attributes of your `solutionEncoding` object, and you seem to expect that every element of the `_population` vector is therefore random.  But this is not the case, since you have only one object.

### Potential solutions

To achieve what you want, you'd need to generate a new pointer to a different object in each iteration.  Just move the line with the `new` into the loop.  But this would not be a good approach, since you would have to do a lot of memory management  (for every `new`, you'd need a `delete`) with some risks (e.g. shallow copy and double deletes).

A safer approach would therefore be to make `_population` a vector containing `solutionEncoding` objects.  `newOne` would also be a `solutionEncoding` object:  `push_back()` would store a different copy each time:

```
std::vector<solutionEncoding> _population; 
...
void initPopulation (unsigned peopleQuantity){
    solutionEncoding newOne{};        // create a new local object - no 'new' needed
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < peopleQuantity; i++ ){
        newOne.generateRandom();        // shuffle all this data :-)
        _population.push_back(newOne);  // store a copy of the current data
    }
}
```

Now this works well if solutionEncoding is not a polymorphic class.  If you'd intend to derive the `solutionEncoding` class in the future,  this would not work because of slicing.  In this case, you'd use a `shared_ptr`:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<solutionEncoding>> _population; 
...
void initPopulation (unsigned peopleQuantity){
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < peopleQuantity; i++ ){
        auto newOne = make_shared<solutionEncoding>(); // create a different new object each time
        newOne->generateRandom();       // shuffle all this data :-)
        _population.push_back(newOne);  // store the pointer to the new object
    }
}
```

Comment: using a raw pointer is always a bad idea, not just becasue of slicing

Comment: @pm100 sorry, I may have missed something, but I did not fully get your point: I think in my answer I explained that raw pointer is a bad idea because of a lot of other problems than slicing.  I mentioned slicing only in relation with polymoprhic vector and I proposed a shared_ptr as alternative, which is far from being a raw pointer, isn't it?

Comment: you do not mention that raw pointer is bad anywhere other than in slicing

Comment: @pm100 Isn't my current sentence not clear enough "*But this would not be a good approach, since you would have to do a lot of memory management (for every new, you'd need a delete) with some risks (e.g. shallow copy and double deletes).*" ? And it not, why?

Comment: a) you say instead to use non heap structs and a) do not mention smart pointers

Comment: @pm10 b) what about the sentence "*In this case, you'd use a shared_ptr*" ?  What is a Shared_ptr according to you ?  a) What is about my first proposal to use local variables instead of pointers?  And by the way,  what do you mean with non-heap struct? If you do not agree with my answer, you are as free as the free-store to post your own, in which you could develop your own arguments ;-)

Comment: look you said 'in this case', 'this case' is derived class causing slicing

Comment: @pm100 I recomended local objects as preferred solution, except if polymorphism is desired for future extendability, in which case it should be shared pointers (pointers if plain objects cannot handle polymorphism). This is factual and argumented and corresponds for each case to the most appropriate choice. If you do not agree or have better arguments, don’t hesitate to propose a better answer: I’d be very interested in seeing your arguments :-)